# How do I cancel Xbox LIVE automatic renewal online?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Is there a way to discontinue your Xbox Live automatic monthly/annual renewal (and credit card charge) over the Web/Internet?

Comment: When I had this issue, I read somewhere that you can only turn it off at the website (and/or console) if there were more than 15 days til your next renewal or something like that. That may be the reason some people has a proper link and some doesn't. My two cents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been trying to do this for weeks and I set myself a rule that I wouldn't call CS nor cancel my DD. As a UK user the "Automatic Renewal:" status isn't a link:

> Automatic renewal: <span id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_AutomaticRenewalStatus">ON</span>

It's ridiculously simple to turn it on, but turning it off the same way is deliberately impossible.

Edit: http://forums.xbox.com/9/31086471/ShowPost.aspx#31086471 (FAQ & Guide - How to turn Automatic Renewal OFF *Please read*) contains the gem "Note: The Auto Renewal ON/OFF feature was removed from all markets except USA, Germany, Taiwan and Japan on the 18th of February 2010." Wonder why..?

Comment: Accepted for containing the single most useful piece of information: ON/OFF feature was removed in most countries (including here in Canada). For you and I, it seems to be impossible to achieve online.

Answer (score 16):

Contrary to what other sites may tell you when Googling around, yes you can cancel your Xbox Live membership renewal without calling customer support.  It's actually really tricky with non-obvious links apparently intended to confound and upset.

After messing around on the Xbox.com website, you may stumble upon the [My Account](https://live.xbox.com/en-US/accounts/MyAccount.aspx) pages (note: US link). In there is a "Membership Level" section which does have an option to disable renewal.  It may be a tiny text link that says "Automatic Renewal: ON", where the word ON is the link.

You should then end up on a page that doesn't look like it's intended for cancelling your renewal at all, but if you scroll down you should find a "Next" button near the bottom.  Hit next through like 3 similar pages - all of which are trying to tell you about all the features you are missing out on by cancelling your membership - until you finally get to the part that actually lets you cancel.

I'd have a better description and some screenshots for you, but I already cancelled mine (through this process) so I can't see the exact pages.

Comment: +1 for truth, if only inside the US and a few other countries

Answer (score 7):

If you log in to Xbox.com and go to your "My Account" page, there is a "Membership Level" section.  It's in there that you can control your billing by enabling or disabling your monthly renewal.

Comment: Just as an FYI ... Microsoft forces you through a few "Are you sure?" screens before your automatic renewal is terminated.

Answer (score 5):

Just found [this gem on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/hm19n/how_to_cancel_xbox_live_auto_renew_without/), for those living where online automatic renewal cancellation is disabled:

> First off, thanks to [eltacodeldiablo](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/hkehk/i_cancelled_my_automatic_renewal_and_microsoft/c1w831u) for pointing me in the right
>   direction. A few days ago there was a deal to get 5 months of Xbox
>   live for $5 which is all well and good except that it turned on
>   automatic renewal for your account which is a pain to turn off. As it
>   turns out, [Illinois](http://www.businessinsider.com/2008/7/final-fantasy-online-s-arcane-cancellation-policy-baffles-lawmakers-leads-to-new-law) passed a law that requires internet gaming service
>   providers to have an online method to cancel the service. So here are
>   the steps to turn off auto renewal for Xbox live:
>
> 1. Go to the [account page](https://live.xbox.com/en-US/account?xr=shellnav)
> 2. Go to Billing Account Information and change the address to
>      somewhere in Illinois
> 3. Back on the account page, go to Manage Payment Options
> 4. Edit the credit card's billing info to be somewhere in Chicago
> 5. Back on the account page, click Upgrade/Manage Account
> 6. Under your avatar where it says Automatic Renewal: On, the On should
>      be a link, click it.
> 7. You are going to have to click next quite a few times but eventually
>      it will give you the option to turn auto renewal off.
> 8. Profit
>
> It takes a few minutes, but is far less painful than calling support
>   and having them potentially cancel your account instead of turning off
>   auto renewal.

**Edit:** This may only work in the US, since changing the country linked to an account seems to be difficult (if not impossible).

Answer (score 4):

Update! Following the cost increase of monthly renewal, MS sent me a nice email detailing the rise and this snippet (UK account, remember):

> As always, you can cancel your membership before the renewal date by calling 0800 587 1103, although we certainly would not want you to miss out on all the great new features and games coming this November.

Useful, except that that number is the TTY device line for the hearing impaired, modem noise and all. The voice line is actually 0800 587 1102. Close, though. I managed to cancel automatic renewal through this number.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

The auto renewal link mentioned by Mag is only available in the US and a few other countries.  The UK isn't included so after two unsucessful calls to CS I sent them an email through the account section on xbox.com and complained.  I got a response asking for a contact phone number and convenient time for them to call, which they did and cancelled it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Lots of old info here, so straight from [the FAQ](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/billing-and-subscriptions/account-management/renew-xbox-live-gold-account):</sub>

> **To turn automatic renewal off:** Click **Sign In** at the top of  **[[Xbox.com]](http://xbox.com)**, or click **My Account** if you’re already signed in. The automatic renewal setting will be displayed near the top-center of the screen. Click **Change** next to **Automatic Renewal**.

[image: xbox.com settings]
<sub>Please edit or comment if this doesn't work in your region.</sub>