# How can I set xbox live to not auto-renew so I don't spend $20 I don't need to?

Tags: xbox-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Discontinue Xbox Live Online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4778/discontinue-xbox-live-online)

Starting 2010-11-01 [Xbox Live is going from $50->$60 per year](http://majornelson.com/archive/2010/08/30/price-change-for-xbox-live-gold-subscription.aspx).  Amazon sells the [12 month subscriptions for $40](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029LJIFG), so I don't see a point in spending $20 I don't need to.

How can I set my Xbox Live subscription to not auto-renew?

Comment: Its worth noting that, if you are on auto-renew right now you can lock in a LOW price even after the price increase: http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/pricelock/default.htm This should solve your problem

Comment: I stand by my vote as long as the question doesn't get edited to ask what @tze is answering (I am aware of the other 42 circumstances where you have the answer before the question) as it is written right now it's a dupe -- Feel free to vote to re-open though.

Comment: Also, you should be able to buy new subscriptions (like at amazon), and apply them now to extend your subscription life so that it won't auto-renew until after that subscription finishes.